# Intalling Craft in the webroot folder

Tags: config, install

I know this is bad practice but it's just for dev sites and there's no easy way around it with our current hosting provider. Anyway, I have my craft folder next to my index.php and $craftpath set to:

```
$craftPath = './craft';
```

Still I get this error:

```
Could not find your craft/ folder. Please ensure that $craftPath is set correctly in /chroot/home/rizencre/rizenweb.com/html/terravant/index.php
```

Answer (score 2):

I just tested it for you and this

```
$craftPath = './craft';
```

or this

```
$craftPath = 'craft';
```

does both work for me!

This probably doesn't help you much; I only wanted to confirm, that your `$craftPath = './craft';` config should be working for your file structure.

Answer (score 2):

Usually when this happens and you're positive the `$craftPath` path is correct, it's one of two things:

1. PHP doesn't have permissions to be able to read the `craft` folder.
2. Your host has [open_basedir](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir) restrictions in place preventing PHP from reading the `craft` folder.